# How to export data from oracle table and import the same contents into table of an external database?

Tags: oracle

I have tried

```
SQL> exp prime/prime@emp1 file=archive.dmp log=archive.log table=ARCHIVE;
```

Should I need to add these in my query,

```
indexes=y trigger=y constraints=n grants=y commit=y
```

what are the significance of these?

Is the import command is same as export?
It it will be like this?

```
SQL> imp prime/prime@emp2 file=archive.dmp log=archive.log table=ARCHIVE;
```

Comment: What version of oracle is this?  You should use expdp/impdp.  They have more options.  Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have said what your issue/error is, so I am guessing, but judging by the "SQL> " prompt in your example, it seems like you are running this from SQL*Plus.

The exp/imp and expdp/impdp utilities are command line programs (DOS/Bash), not sub-commands within sqlplus.

To run "within" sqlplus you have to "host out" as follows:

Portable:

```
SQL> HOST imp ....
```

Unix/Linux:

```
SQL> ! imp ....
```

DOS:

```
SQL> $ imp.exe .....
```